# Why is my HttpClient call not returning expected Json?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a client service. In that service, I have the following method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Client>> ReadAsync()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connString)) 
    using (var cmdRead = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Client", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var ret = new List<Client>();

        var reader = await cmdRead.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var client = BuildFromDataReader(reader);
            ret.Add(client);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

This method is called by a Web API controller action like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Client>> Get()
{
    // API side.
    IEnumerable<Client> clients = await _clients.ReadAsync();
    return clients;
}
```

I would expect the default for content negotiation to be JSON and as such expect this action to return a JSON encoded `Client` list.

My client of all this attempts to consume the Web API looks more like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Client>> ReadAsync()
{
    var json = await Client.GetStringAsync("api/Clients/Get");
    var clients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Client>>(json);
    return clients;
}
```

On inspection at a breakpoint, `json` has the value `"value"` (quotes included). What have I tried? The code above. Where is the json I expect returned by the Web API action?

**PS:** I am busy on an ASP.NET Core project, so we are using NewtonSoft JSON as well.

Comment: Hold on I am taking a look. quick question. is the web service web api 2 or asp.net core?

Comment: What's inside the `Client.GetStringAsync` method?  You said that `Client` is your business object representing a client of your business, not a communication client, right?

Comment: @ProfK the question is salvageable is you provide a [mcve]. Right now there are just too many questions needed to ask to clarify the problem.  Brian asked a good question about the `GetStringAsync`. That is one point of failure.I assumed it is from HttpClient.  There is also the way the web api is designed.

Comment: Have you tried using something like Postman or curl to hit the `api/Clients/Get` endpoint?

Comment: @Nkosi I do state in the question, at the bottom, that it is core.

Comment: @ProfK I misunderstood the PS. as being another project. My bad then

Comment: @BrianRogers No, 'Client' is 'HttpClient', and as to what goes on inside; it's part of .NET, not my code.

Comment: So what is returned when you access that url in browser? And with your httpclient request do you really get "value" back, not even client list in some form (not json)?

Comment: @ProfK, OK, followup question then: if `Client` is actually an HttpClient, then why are you trying to deserialize a list of them on the very next line?

Comment: @BrianRogers I was expecting to receive JSON back from the API controller action. The natural thing to do is try and deserialize it.

Comment: The problem is resolved, thank you, everybody.

Answer (score 1):

I think the down votes are due to you expressing an assumption without verifying your facts.

A simple three step google search leads to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation which details what standards webapi uses for content negotiation.

As you can see from that your assumption is incorrect - aren't assumptions always incorect?

Json is only returned if the request states that as what it will accept. So you need to set the accept header on the request to accept Json. To quote the article:

`GET http://localhost.:21069/api/products/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost.:21069
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`

Comment: You are correct about my assumption and I apologize to members for whom that assumption made the question difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a very unlikely point of failure, but I've come across it many, many times while researching `HttpClient` and this problem.

It looks like the `BaseAddress` string property must end in a trailing "/". I don't know if I inadvertently changed something else, but as soon as I added that trailing slash, I was back in business. E.g. the slash after the port number:

```
private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63675/") };
```